# Installing MATLAB 2017a onto Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I am a new Ubuntu user, so I have little experience in installation. I have downloaded the Matlab 2017a .zip file from the mathworks website and have tried to unzip the file using `unzip <file name>` but that didn't work. I got this dialogue `unzip:cannot find or open <file name>`. So I tried to find the directory so that I could follow another set of install instructions using `cd /home/usr/downloads/file name`
but that did not work either as I received `bash: cd: /home/usr/downloads/file name.zip: not a directory`. As of right now I have the .zip sitting in my downloads folder, and have extracted the files using Xarchiver. I don't know what to do to install it from here.

Comment: the trouble is you tried to cd into a file. You need to cd into a directory, `cd home/usr/downloads` and then `unzip file.zip`